# Query throwing error; "column ambiguously defined"

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am running a query as

```
SELECT LOCATION_OID,UPPER(NAME) AS LOCATION_NAME FROM LOCATION LEFT OUTER JOIN LOCATION_CHILD_LOCATION parent on (parent.LOCATION_OID = LOCATION.LOCATION_OID)
```

There are two table LOCATION and LOCATION_CHILD_LOCATION, Location has some 456 records and location_child_location has 4 records. The records in location_child_location are mapped with the location_oid from the parent i.e location table.
Why is this query giving error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the table from which you want the `LOCATION_OID` else the analyzer will confuse as to which table it has to look to fetch the data. Try this:

```
SELECT LOCATION.LOCATION_OID,UPPER(NAME) AS LOCATION_NAME 
FROM LOCATION LEFT OUTER JOIN LOCATION_CHILD_LOCATION parent
 on (parent.LOCATION_OID = LOCATION.LOCATION_OID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the table name in front of the `LOCATION_OID` in the `select` clause:

```
SELECT LOCATION.LOCATION_OID,UPPER(NAME) AS LOCATION_NAME FROM LOCATION LEFT OUTER JOIN LOCATION_CHILD_LOCATION on (parent.LOCATION_OID = LOCATION.LOCATION_OID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query where Naming is properly mentioned to avoid conflict in Table Namings:

```
SELECT l.LOCATION_OID,UPPER(NAME) AS LOCATION_NAME 
FROM LOCATION as l
LEFT OUTER JOIN LOCATION_CHILD_LOCATION parent on (parent.LOCATION_OID = LOCATION.LOCATION_OID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use aliases for each tables instead of mixing both approach (with and without aliases):

```
SELECT L.LOCATION_OID
    ,UPPER(L.NAME) AS LOCATION_NAME
FROM LOCATION L
LEFT OUTER JOIN LOCATION_CHILD_LOCATION P ON P.LOCATION_OID = L.LOCATION_OID
```

Hope this will help.